# Why does a C program consisting of one source file still need the linking phase?

Tags: c

Why is a linking phase needed?

If I have this program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    float c=pow(8,5.6);
    printf(" Result =%f",c);
    return 0;
}
```

I guess it needs to perform the linker phase for the library Math.h?

Comment: "stdion.h not found".

Comment: @Sonja Ićeva and for the `stdio`. You don't have "one source file" you have three.

Comment: this program is in test.cpp

Comment: It needs to be linked with the C runtime library.

Comment: so one source file why three? Weather Vane

Comment: @SonjaIćeva because you included two other source files, which themselves could include more.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you don't use any functions, the program still needs to be linked with the standard C runtime library. This provides the wrapper code that calls `main()`, and calls `exit()` when the `main()` function returns.

Comment: So the main function main() comes from the standard C runtime library

Comment: Yes. Other languages have different names for their starting function.

Answer (score 0):

Your program use two functions you didn't defined yourself: `printf` and `pow`, so to produce an executable there must be a link to the code of these. But even if you don't use any external function (fairly rare and not commonly useful) there is a need to set up the runtime before going into your defined code (some different technical things are usually needed for your code to behave correctly).